# How to clone an item of objects in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, reference

I have an array as given below -

```
var x = [{
    name: "Mr.X", 
    age: 22
},{
    name: "Mr.Y", 
    age: 26
},{
    name: "Mr.Z", 
    age: 24
},];
```

I want to duplicate the 2nd item and put it as the first element. Just to avoid any confusion, I want the resultant array to be as given below -

```
var x = [{
    name: "Mr.YD", 
    age: 19
},{
    name: "Mr.X", 
    age: 22
},{
    name: "Mr.Y", 
    age: 26
},{
    name: "Mr.Z", 
    age: 24
},];
```

What I have tried and got - I extracted the 2nd item, and changed the `name` and `age` properties. But it is also changing the 2nd item. I know it is because we are changing the reference. But i have no idea how to extract/duplicate item and change only its value.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to clone an existing object in the array instead of just creating a new one?

Comment: Refer this: http://jsfiddle.net/e7kLb9f8/

Comment: I didn't follow your question. But the resultant array could be "y" instead of "x".

Comment: @RayonDabre - Only one thing - the result should also be an array of objects, just like the input.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is being used just to demonstrate the result..You can remove it!

Comment: are the real objects just "plain old data" or are they the result of some sort of constructor function?

Comment: @RayonDabre - Your solution works...but i did not understand what are we doing with the JSON stringify and parse?

Comment: In your code, you are changing the reference of the object and that is why it is changing 2nd item too. Using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`, we are cloning object that is making copy of the array and then changing it..

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = [{
    name: "Mr.X", 
    age: 22
},{
    name: "Mr.Y", 
    age: 26
},{
    name: "Mr.Z", 
    age: 24
},];
console.log(x);
var y = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
y.unshift({
    name: "Mr.XD", 
    age: 19
});
console.log(y);
```

1. Unshift appends on top of array
2. Push appends on the end of array

Comment: while it usually works, I would never recommend using JSON just to clone an object.

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for clone of the object
there are multiple ways

jQuery Extend:

```
// Shallow copy
  var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, oldObject);

  // Deep copy
  var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);
```

JSON Stringify

```
var newObject =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObject))
```

Or :
Write a clone method by iterating through object props recursively

Then append to the array using the standard array APIs